# Iframe isnt working after mapping in nginx

Tags: javascript, nginx, iframe, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I mapped my ip to 192.168.1.13:9443 in nginx but when I access my application it is giving

`Refused to frame 'https://192.168.1.13:9443/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".`
My configuration in nginx to map it is:
`location /{ proxy_pass  https://192.168.1.13:9443; }`